# What exactly does "great" mean in "Make America great again"?

Tags: meaning

Does Trump mean "very big" (in power, not in size) or "wonderful"?

Comment: Looking for precise meanings in politicians' slogans? Not sure that's wise….

Comment: It's a political slogan, which means it means whatever it means to you.  If it was defined as one thing, it would fail to attract people who want it to mean something else.  The whole idea is to sound good and be vague so you can project your own objectives onto it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that this can be confusing.  As you've noticed, "great" can mean anything from "wonderful", to "important", to "excellent", to "powerful" and to even "large".

The point is that the slogan is very vague and so the meaning depends  largely on the audience's interpretation. Generally, this depends on their values. If for example the supporters endorse a particular military policy and Trump intends to implement it, then in the supporters' opinion, Trump's implementation  will make America "great" again. Since the military is generally associated with strength, you could interpret it as making America "strong" again.

You can apply a similar logic to the many political issues, but that will only get you so far. Again, the interpretations will vary from one person to another, and that's what makes it appealing.